# the correct way to append an input element to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far anytime i have needed to add an input to a form dynamically i have done:

```
 var row = "<input type='text' id='someId' name='someName' value='someValue'>";
 $('#form').append(row);
```

I know there is a better way. I have read about setAttribute or .attr(). how would i start?

```
 var input = ???;
  input.attr('type','text');
  input.attr('id','someId');
  input.attr('name','someName');
  input.attr('val','someValue');
  input.attr('type','text');

 $('#form').append(input);
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with doing it the way you first showed. There are other ways, but they are not necessarily better, just different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a better way exist,

```
 $('#form').append($("<input>",{
   "type" : "text",
   "id" : "someId",
   "name" : "someName",
   "value" : "someValue"
 }));
```

Don't mix up pure jquery with javascript. That may results in error sometimes. like invoking jquery functions over node object. Ex : `node.css(...)`

Comment: And, why is this better than just creating the element with a string?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It is more readable and maintainable. And It excludes the usage of creating another one variable (at least for this context).

Comment: You don't need the variable to work with the string version and, as for readability and maintainability, that's just a matter of opinion. There is really no quantifiable way to say that your way is better than the original way or even using `document.createElement` - they are all just different ways.

Comment: is this the proper place to elaborate on this question which will change alot of these answers or ask a new question?

Comment: @bart2puck You can add anything about the question here. But do not change the entire plot of the same'

Comment: so instead of appending to a form, i want the input element added as a row in a table. which in turn will be appended to the parent form.

Comment: @bart2puck  `$("<td>").appendTo($("<tr>").appendTo("#table")).append($("<input>"))`

Comment: @bart2puck I simply given a sample. Better you ask a new question for that. Because the current question's context is different from what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

When I need to add elements dynamically I do the following:

```
var $_form = $("#form");
$("<input/>",{ id : "input_1",type : "text", val : "value" }).addClass("class1 class2").appendTo($_form);
```

This form works for any element, not just form fields.

Answer (score 0):

For brevity you can just do the following, all in one line:

```
$('#form').append("<input type='text' id='someId' name='someName' value='someValue'>");
```

but for more complex cases you can take the longer approach:

```
$("<input/>", {
    attributes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript's [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), like so:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
//and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

As @scottmarcus has pointed out this is is not necessarily better but different. It's what you're looking for:

```
var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
```

Which is a DOM element; so you cannot use jQuery methods such as `.attr()`. You would have to use JavaScript methods such as `setAttribute()`. In order to use jQuery methods all you have to do is to wrap input in `$` like so:

```
var input = $( document.createElement("INPUT") );
```

A better way to write this would be:

```
var input = $('<input/>');
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement