# appending form elements to a table

Tags: jquery

Currently I am doing the following:

```
 var row = "<tr>";
 $("#addServiceForm input, #addServiceForm select").each(function(index){
      row += "<td><input type='text' id='someId' name='someName' value='someValue'></td>";
  });
  var row "</tr>";

 $('#someTable').append(row);
```

my pseudo-issue is that row line gets long. 
I was trying to do it in a more readable fashion.  A previous question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342850/the-correct-way-to-append-an-input-element-to-a-form) helped with the element portion when appending to form, what about appending a row and input to a table?

```
$("#addServiceForm input, #addServiceForm select").each(function(index){
   var element = $('<input>',{
     id:idName,
     name:idName,
     val:thisVal
    }).addClass('verify');
 row += "<td class='verify'>"+element+"</td>";
});
$('#someTable').append(row);
```

does not work. I end up with:

```
 <td>[OBJECT]</td>
```

based on your answer, what is the best way to shorten:

```
var row = "<td><input type='text' id='someIdthatisLong' name='someNamethatisLong' value='someValuethatislong' class='verify' readonly='readonly'></td>";
```

Comment: I would stay with your initial code example. If the single line gets too long, just break it and carry on appending to the string. Your second example doesn't work as `element` is a jQuery object so cannot be directly appended to a string. You could make the second example work by placing a call to `append()` in the each loop, but this is a (relatively) slow operation hence why your first example is preferable as it only uses a single append.

Comment: thank you. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work with objects, you need to use them consistently, not mix them with strings.

```
var row = $("<tr>");
$("#addServiceForm input, #addServiceForm select").each(function(index){
   var element = $('<input>',{
     id:idName,
     name:idName,
     val:thisVal,
     'class': 'verify'
    });
   row.append($("<td>").append(element));
});
$('#someTable').append(row);
```

However, this isn't necessarily the most efficient way to do it. The browser's HTML parser is extremely efficient, so parsing a big HTML string may be better than creating all the individual objects in Javascript and connecting them together.